# Windows 8 lock screen path/reg key

Tags: windows-8

Does anyone know the actual path used for the Windows 8 lock screen background image, or if it has a registry key? Is it even stored as a file? I know how to change it, I want to recover the image currently in use.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [answer of Karan](https://superuser.com/a/497175/290156) gived me the right path. Your customs lockscreens are located in the `SystemData` folder, but as you are going to see this folder is not accessible. You don't have the right to open or copy it even as an administrator. You have to take the ownership. No need to use a VM.

Open a console (Win+S "cmd") as administrator (right click "run as administrator") and run this command:

```
takeown /F "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\SystemData" /R /D Y
```

I used my own path to the folder, it mights differs for yours.

After navigates to find folders LockScreen_A, LockScreen_B, etc. Each letters are linked to one of our customs lockscreens.

[image: LockScreen_B]

Just copy the one you want and it is done.

[source](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-desktop/where-is-the-windows-8-lockscreen-wallpaper-stored/8866eaa5-fa5b-4e2c-9d47-871a04fb44ba)

Answer (score 7):

Look in the `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\SystemData\S-1-5-18\ReadOnly` directory. Under that you should see some sub-dirs like `LockScreen_X`, `LockScreen_Y`, `LockScreen_Z` etc. Each one will contain a different wallpaper named something like `LockScreen___Width_Height.jpg` (basically the images you selected, but resized/cropped to fit your screen resolution).

Comment: Interesting, Windows won't actually allow me to look in SystemData at all, I'm loathed to take ownership (assuming it will even let me) in case that messes everythihng else up :/

Comment: I didn't mind (taking ownership) since I did it in a VM. :) Maybe you can try accessing the files by using a Linux LiveCD/USB?

Comment: How infuriating, I'll give it a go with a live cd and see what I can find.

Answer (score 6):

The image for the lock screen is located in `C:\Windows\Web\Screen`. The image name is `img000.png`.

Comment: Thanks, for my system that includes the default screens, but not my lock screen, or a file called img000.png :/