# Remove lock screen wallpaper in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1

When accessing a remote system through TeamViewer or AnyDesk displaying the lock screen takes a long time because of the wallpaper. So it may be desirable to remove this wallpaper ("to set it to "). How to remove lock screen wallpaper (make it blank) in Windows 8.1?

Answer (score 0):

To disable the lock screen image in Windows 10:

- Go to *Start > Settings > Personalization > Lock Screen*
- Scroll down and toggle off
  "Show Windows background picture on the sign-in screen"
- The effect is immediate, reboot not required.

Comment: Note: There is probably a registry setting for this, but I didn't research it.

Comment: See [this link](https://www.eightforums.com/threads/lock-screen-background-image-set-default-in-windows-8.14485/) for Windows 8.1, if you have the requirements.

Answer (score -1):

It may be done by launching the following script:

```
@echo off
takeown.exe /F "%SystemDrive%\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\SystemData" /R /D Y
for /r %SystemDrive%\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\SystemData\S-1-5-18\ReadOnly %%A in (*) do echo y|cacls.exe "%%A" /s:"D:PAI(D;;CC;;;SY)(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-80-956008885-3418522649-1831038044-1853292631-2271478464)(A;;FA;;;SY)"
```

To revert everything back:

```
@echo off
for /r %SystemDrive%\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\SystemData\S-1-5-18\ReadOnly %%A in (*) do echo y|cacls.exe "%%A" /s:"D:PAI(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-80-956008885-3418522649-1831038044-1853292631-2271478464)(A;;FA;;;SY)"
```

Based on [Windows 8 lock screen path/reg key](https://superuser.com/questions/497087/windows-8-lock-screen-path-reg-key)

Comment: Never, ever, take ownership of a Windows protected folder. You can't "revert everything back" - ReadOnly is not enough.

Comment: Under "revert everything back" I mean - restore the wallpaper. Sure I'm able to revert the ownership of the folder, too, I just don't see much sense in it. Anyway, M$ doesn't offer the better way to solve the case.

Comment: I added a method in my answer for Windows 10. No idea if it exists for Windows 8.1 (upgrade is *very* recommended).

Comment: No it doesn't exist for Windows 8.1. And no, upgrade is not recommended until you can live without it.

Comment: Search out the registry setting. Live without the safest version of Windows is to live badly...

Comment: I did. There's no registry setting for it. I don't care much for the so-called safety if I can't have the usability.